# add more vocabulary to pretrained word2vec model

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-mining, gensim, word2vec

help me to correct this or are there any other way to accomplish this task?

[image: Snapshot of code snippet]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post code as text and not images so it is searchable

Answer (score 1):

`build_vocab()` needs a list-of-texts (list of list-of-tokens) – you're just giving it a list of words, so each word is being considered a single text, and the only new words that might be added by your code are single letters.

But also:

- `min_count=1` is usually bad for vector-quality
- `epochs=150` is way higher than the usual 5-10 iterations - somewhat higher than that might be helpful for small datasets but 100+ is excessive
- incrementally adding vocabulary/training won't necessarily improve your model; in particular when you train with new examples that don't include the whole vocabulary (and range of uses), only some words in the model get adjusted – and are potentially moved *out-of-alignment* with other words known only from earlier training

The most robust thing to do, when there's new texts including new words, is to re-train the whole model, with all old and new texts mixed together. That best assures equal attention & compatible coordinates between all words.

If you do incremental training using new texts, with or without having expanded the vocabulary, you should carefully watch whatever custom evaluations of overall model quality you have, to be sure what you're doing is helping.